# Laravel 5 not generating api token on register

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have added a column for api_token and in my register controller , while creating the user I am trying to generate a unique id , but its not generating any code . Here is my create user function in register controller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'api_token' => md5($data['email'].$data['name']),
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Do I need to add this somewhere else?

Comment: @DanielGale yes, I did that

Comment: Did you add `api_token` to your in your User model in `$fillable` ?

Comment: Even if I am changing this to 'api_token' => md5('deepak'),  its not populating the field

Comment: @cbaconnier My bad , yes added now and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As [cbaconnier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8068675/cbaconnier) mentioned, you also need to add `api_token` to your $fillable array in the User model.